# Does this set contain zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, Let's define a set $P_x$ as such:

$$P_x=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\,\mid\,y=x^n \text{ for some } n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

The question is, for $x=\frac{1}{2}$, does $P_x$ contain $0$? As I understand it, $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^n=0$, but does that mean that zero is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ raised to some $n$?

Comment: No.  $0 \not\in P_{1/2}$ ... for every integer $n$ we have $(1/2)^n > 0$.  Even if you write $(1/2)^\infty = 0$ for some bogus reason, still $\infty \not\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: No, $\Bbb R$ is an integral domain and $1/2 \neq 0$, so $(1/2)^n \neq 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: The limit being zero is a separate matter to whether or not zero is included in the set itself.  That the limit is zero implies that for any imperfect precision we want, we will eventually reach and remain within that level of precision.  $\frac{1}{2}^n$ is eventually for large enough $n$ within one decimal place from zero.  It is eventually within ten decimal places from zero.  It is eventually within fifty-billion decimal places from zero, and so on...  That the limit is zero does not however imply that it is eventually zero exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The set does not contain zero. One way to think about it is that $\frac{1}{2}^n$ is just the product $ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}...\frac{1}{2},$ $n$ times. Since a product is only zero if one of its factors is zero, and since $\frac{1}{2} \not= 0$, the product is not zero, no matter how large $n$ is. Thus 0 is not in the set.

I hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it holds that

$\forall  p \in P_{\frac{1}{2}} \exists r \in \mathbb{R}^+ (0 < r < p)  $

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty  } (\frac{1}{2})^n = 0$$

But every element will be in the interval [$\frac{1}{2}$,0) and never reach 0.

If you think iteratively about it, even if the element of $P_{\frac{1}{2}}$ corresponding to n=m will be very small, the element corresponding to n=m+1 will always be, independent of m, twice as small, but still larger than 0.